# How do I completely turn off the infotainment center in my 2017 Chev Impala without raising the screen?

Tags: chevrolet, impala, infotainment

My car is going to be used by a new driver for a road test soon.  In this province, much of the information displayed on the infotainment screen is an automatic fail on the road test.  Back up display, warning indicators etc.  The only way I've found to completely turn it off is by sliding the screen up.  Unfortunately, this impedes a clear forward view.

I haven't been able to find anything in either the vehicle user manual or the infotainment manual.  I'm beginning to think I may have to cover the screen with a piece of cardboard for the test.   I'd like to be sure the new driver isn't disqualified because of this.

I just went for a look and found the settings menu.  It allows you to turn off the display; but, the moment you shift to reverse the display kicks back in.

Thank you  :)

Comment: Possible to just pull the fuse out, so no power goes to that device?  That takes like 30 seconds  (assuming you know which fuse it is).

Comment: @zipzit Thank you, I'm thinking fuse for rear camera...   :)

Comment: Cover it with cardboard.

Comment: @moab  I'm going to go with the fuses first.  If it doesn't work, I will call ICBC and see what they advise.  If all else fails, I am going with the cardboard.  LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in the manual for the vehicle that it has a valet mode, which disables a number of settings on the infotainment system, but I suspect that the feature list that would be disabled does not meet your requirements.

The next stop was the stand-alone infotainment manual, also lacking in useful information.

All is not lost.

The overall vehicle manual specifies for the instrument panel fuse box, mini-fuse 5 corresponds to Cluster/Auxiliary Jack/HMI/USB/Radio Display/CD player.

I'm not sure what HMI means and I fear that Cluster may indicate your standard instrument cluster, but maybe not. It's relatively harmless to pull a fuse to make such a test, but ensure that if your vehicle has a security code for the radio gear that you know what it is before you pull the plug, figuratively speaking.

[image: instrument panel fuse block]

Comment: Thank you.  I had given up on their main manual after reading that during a blizzard I should pull over, stay with my vehicle and call for help.  I have to wonder if the On Star still works after the truck coming ten miles back creams my vehicle six ways from Sunday.  Now I'll check the fuse box and pull the rear camera.  HMI (I had to look it up) is Human Machine Interface  :)

Comment: @ fred_dot_u   My apologies, I need two more points to vote you up.  I will work on that now.  :)

Comment: @ fred_dot_u  made it back and up you go  :)

Answer (score 0):

A call to ICBC has alleviated any concerns in this matter.  Changes were made to the laws in 2018 to accommodate the features of the computer systems in vehicles.

Their manual 'Learn to Drive Smart,' chapter 5, Pg 61 sates:

> Blind spot detectors, cameras — Some vehicles are equipped with blind spot detectors and/or back-up cameras. While these can help you to detect hazards in blind spots or behind the vehicle, they do not replace the need to turn your head to do a shoulder check or look behind.
>
> Shoulder checks — whenever you plan to change your direction or road
>   position, do a shoulder check to make sure the blind spot on that side
>   is clear.

Other features that do not require disabling are auto braking and lane assist.

A full copy of ICBC Learn to Drive Smart can be downloaded free at:  https://www.icbc.com/driver-licensing/Documents/driver-full.pdf